# How to write an Aerospike stream UDF for a range Query

Tags: java, lua, stream, udf, aerospike

I wrote a Stream UDF for a range Query and it doesn't work properly. have you any idea how to set many filters with lua ?

The query:

```
SELECT id1, id2, link_type, visibility, data, time, version FROM linktable
WHERE id1 = <id1> AND
  link_type = <link_type> AND
  time >= <minTime> AND
  time <= <maxTimestamp> AND
  visibility = VISIBILITY_DEFAULT
ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT <offset>, <limit>;
```

Java code to invoke this lua function:

```
stmt = new Statement();
stmt.setNamespace(dbid);
stmt.setSetName("links");
stmt.setIndexName("time");
stmt.setFilters(Filter.range("time", minTimestamp, maxTimestamp));
stmt.setAggregateFunction("linkbench", "check_id1", Value.get(id1));
stmt.setAggregateFunction("linkbench", "check_linktype", Value.get(link_type));
resultSet = client.queryAggregate(null, stmt, "linkbench", "check_visibility", Value.get(VISIBILITY_DEFAULT));
```

Lua Script:

```
local function map_links(record)
    -- Add user and password to returned map.
    -- Could add other record bins here as well.
    return record.id2
end

function check_id1(stream,id1)
    local function filter_id1(record)
        return record.id1 == id1
    end
    return stream : filter(filter_id1) : map(map_links)
end

function check_linktype(stream,link_type)
    local function filter_linktype(record)
        return record.link_type == link_type
    end
    return stream : filter(filter_linktype) : map(map_links)
end

function check_visibility(stream,visibility)
    local function filter_visibility(record)
        return record.visibility == visibility
    end
    return stream : filter(filter_visibility) : map(map_links)
end
```

Any idea how to write the filter for all the query restrictions ?

Thank you!

Comment: Concurrently also discussed at: https://discuss.aerospike.com/t/record-manipulation-with-more-than-one-filter-lua/3637

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since [release 3.12](http://www.aerospike.com/blog/whats-new-aerospike-3-12/) a [predicate filter](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/guide/predicate.html) would be the correct approach, avoiding Lua completely for better performance and scalability.

Take a look at the [PredExp](http://www.aerospike.com/apidocs/java/com/aerospike/client/query/PredExp.html) class of the Java client and its [examples](https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-client-java/blob/master/examples/src/com/aerospike/examples/QueryPredExp.java#L203-L211) for building complex filters. Predicate filtering also currently exists for the  [C](http://www.aerospike.com/apidocs/c/d9/d10/as__predexp_8h_source.html), [C#](http://www.aerospike.com/apidocs/csharp/html/T_Aerospike_Client_PredExp.htm) and [Go](https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-client-go/blob/master/predexp.go) clients.

Comment: Just a note, you cannot do an ORDER BY on the server side . You'd have to catch the records matching the predicate filter on the application side and sort there.

Comment: Wonderful. I almost wasted a couple of days figuring out how can I combilne multiple filters in Aerospike. Now things looks like working. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Multiple aggregation functions are not supported.  Aggregation and Filter functions must be combined.

```
function combined_aggregation(stream,id1,link_type,visibility)
    local function combined_filter(record)
        return record.id1 == id1 and 
               record.link_type == link_type and
               record.visibility == visibility
    end
    return stream : filter(combined_filter) : map(map_links)
end
```